# Should I use exceptions to handle user input validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm in the process of moving my business logic code from my controllers to business classes.  My page requires a lot of user input validation.  This created many nesting levels in my code.   So I re-wrote the code in my business layer to look like this:

```
    public RmaDetail SerialNumberScan(int rmaNumber, int serialNumber, RepairInvoice repairInvoice) {
    var result = SelectRmaDetail(rmaNumber, serialNumber);

    if (result != null) throw new BusinessException("Serial Number not found.");

    if (result.Received != 1) throw new BusinessException("Line item has not been received.");

    bool? workOrderClosed = WorkOrderClosed(result.LNSEQNBR, result.LNSEQNBR, serialNumber);

    if (!workOrderClosed.HasValue) throw new BusinessException("Work order not found.");

    if (workOrderClosed.Value == false) throw new BusinessException("Work order not closed.");

    repairInvoice.TerminalType = result.ITEMNMBR.Trim();
    repairInvoice.UnderWarranty = RepairInvoiceDataLayer.UnderWarranty(result.RETDOCID, result.LNSEQNBR, serialNumber, result.CUSTNMBR);

    return result;
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult SerialNumberScan(string rmaNumber, string serialNumber)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState["SerialNumber"].Value = new ValueProviderResult(serialNumber, serialNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        try
        {
            var rmaDetail = BusinessLayer.SerialNumberScan(rmaNumber, serialNumber, repairInvoice);
            Session["RmaDetail"] = rmaDetail;
            ViewBag.SetFocusTo = "#RepairLevels";
        }
        catch (BusinessException ex)
        {
            ViewBag.AlertMessage = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    return View("Index", repairInvoice);
}
```

The line `ViewBag.AlertMessage` is a message that displays at the top of my page.  I like this approach because it is very readable.  However, I know that exceptions are very expensive.  Is there a better approach?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a general code review of a method (consider posting on codereview.SE), rather than a question about a specific problem with it.

Comment: Throwing exception and then handling it, I would say is very costly.. Instead create a generic class that had error/success code, message, data (object) as attributes.. Fill the object with appropriate error and message. Inside view check the is the operation successful if no display error message.

Comment: @LearningByCoding could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions become expensive only when you throw them as part of a normal program flow. In general, exceptions should be used for handling exceptional situations, so your use case definitely qualifies: situations when serial numbers or line items are missing are indeed exceptional.

One thing that I would change, though, is the use of the same exception (namely, `BusinessException`) to deal with all your validation. On one hand, this makes your code very simple, because you always throw the same exception - the only thing that is different is the message. On the other hand, it takes away your flexibility to handle each situation differently.

I think that introducing sublcasses to `BusinessException` would lead to a better approach. Add new exceptions - in this case, `MissingSerialNumber` and `MissingLineItem` exceptions, make them subclasses of `BusinessException` so that you could handle them together if you wish, and use no-argument constructor at the points where you throw these exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Exceptions are only expensive if they are thrown.  And they should be thrown if there is a problem.  In terms of performance, I don't think you should be worrying about it in this scenario, we're not talking *seconds* here, we're talking milliseconds.  The user sure isn't going to notice the expense of throwing the exception and telling them.

Also off-topic, you could write an extension method such as this:

```
    public static void Throw<T>(this bool expression, string alert) where T : Exception
    {
        if (!expression)
            throw (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), alert);
    }
```

Then you could replace all those if/throw checks with:

```
(result.Received != 1).Throw<BusinessException>("message");
```